# Tooltip is cutoff using google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

The tooltip gets cutoff for certain points (the bottom part gets cutoff).
How can I fix this issue?

following are the current options...

```
chart.draw(data, {
    width: 275, 
    height: 75, 
    legend:'none',
    gridlineColor:'white',
    pointSize:2, 
    chartArea:{left:0},
    chartArea:{width:275},
    colors:['red','green', 'blue']});
```

Comment: set tooltip z-index to 1200 like this.

Answer (score 5):

use the `tooltip.ignoreBounds` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

from the documentation...

> If set to **true**, allows the drawing of tooltips to flow outside of the bounds of the chart on all sides.

Comment: You answered it 5 years after it was asked, and helped me 3 years after you answered. You're a real one.